# Nestjs - Controlador no está devolviendo todas las propiedades del objeto

Tags: javascript, api, typescript

Estoy usando NestJs conectado con mongoDb. Los objetos que se guardan en mongo tiene la siguiente estructura `{NAME: string, YEAR: number, COVER: string}`.

Las interfaces y los dtos son:

```
export class NAME {
    readonly NAME: string;
    readonly YEAR: number;
    readonly COVER: string;
    COVER_BASE64: string;
}

export interface NAME extends Document {
    readonly NAME: string;
    readonly YEAR: number;
    readonly COVER: string;
    COVER_BASE64: string;
}
```

En el servicio tengo la siguiente funcion que lo que hace es coger los objetos de mongo y le añade la propiedad COVER_BASE64 a los objetos.

```
async getAlbums(): Promise<Album[]> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.model.find().exec((err, objs) => {
                if (err) { reject(err); }
                const objres = objs.map(obj => {
                    const base64 = this.getBase64(obj);
                    obj.COVER_BASE64 = base64;
                    return obj;
                });
                resolve(objsres);
            });
        });
   }
```

El problema es que los objetos devueltos en el controlador no tienen la propiedad COVER_BASE64, pero debugueando el servicio si que se estan devolviendo los objetos con la propiedad COVER_BASE64 con el valor esperado. Pero debugueando el controlador dicha propiedad no existe en los objetos.

¿Hay alguna razon por la que la propiedad no llegue al controlador y por consiguiente se deuelva en la llamada http?

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta, estas en SO en español